# How to extract all required chunks in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I create a syntax tree(with a code downside) and what I need is to extract all NPs from it. How  I know loops are not working here normally, so I will be happy for your suggestions.

```
`import nltk
from nltk import RegexpParser, pos_tag

sentence = open('text.txt', 'r')
sentence = sentence.read()

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

tagged = pos_tag(tokens)

chunker = RegexpParser("""
  NP: {<DT|JJ|NN.*>+}          # Chunk sequences of DT, JJ, NN
  PP: {<IN><NP>}               # Chunk prepositions followed by NP
  VP: {<VB.*><NP|PP|CLAUSE>+$} # Chunk verbs and their arguments
  CLAUSE: {<NP><VP>}           # Chunk NP, VP
  """)

output = chunker.parse(tagged)`
```

I'm expect to extract all NP from given syntax tree:

```
(S
  (NP The/DT charming/JJ Gothic/NNP Quarter/NNP)
  ,/,
  or/CC
  (NP Barri/NNP Gòtic/NNP)
  ,/,
  has/VBZ
  (NP narrow/JJ medieval/JJ streets/NNS)
  filled/VBN
  (PP with/IN (NP trendy/JJ bars/NNS))
  ,/,
  (NP clubs/NNS)
  and/CC
  (NP Catalan/NNP restaurants/NNS)
  ./.)
```